# "there are tours that worth it" or "there are tours that ARE worth it"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is sentence "Anyway, there are definitely some bus tours that worth it, for example..." fully correct in  terms of grammar? My friend wrote it in some letter for english exam and he quite confidently insists that there should be no second "are" in this structure whereas I just don't get why in the world would you cut out "to be" before an adjective. This led to a sudden small civil war between us... Would be really grateful if you could somehow enlighten me and bring peaceful times back to our streets).

Comment: Your friend is wrong - it should be _that are worth it_.

Comment: You might hear people say: **There are bus tours worth it**, signifying **bus tours that are worth it.** But, as Kate says, once you include **that**, you have to follow with the verb (are).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a "typo" - either ***that** shouldn't be there at all, or (more likely) it should be followed by ***are***